# Writing data to a file in python

Tags: python, file

I keep getting this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Bayofagbenro.txt'
```

Here is my code:

```py
def main():
    outfile = open('Bayofagbenro.txt')
    Bayofagbenro =outfile.write ('Modupeola\n')
    Bayofagbenro =outfile.w ('Ayobami\n')
    Bayofagbenro =outfile.w ('AKintola\n')
    Bayofagbenro =outfile.w ('Omonike\n')
    Bayofagbenro =outfile.w ('Fehintoluwa\n')
    Bayofagbenro =outfile.w ('Modupeola is 44yrs, Ayobami is 42 years, AKintola is 38 years, omonike is 36 years while fehintoluwa is 30 years')
    outfile = Bayofagbenro.r

    outfile.close

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

While expecting something like this:

[image: expected output]

Comment: try with `open('Bayofagbenro.txt', 'w')` you need to specify that you want to write to it

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```py
def main():
    with open('Bayofagbenro.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('Modupeola\n')
        f.write('Ayobami\n')
        f.write('AKintola\n')
        f.write('Omonike\n')
        f.write('Fehintoluwa\n')
        f.write('Modupeola is 44yrs, Ayobami is 42 years, AKintola is 38 years, omonike is 36 years while fehintoluwa is 30 years')
```

Comment: This is correct answer, @Akinola you are trying write data to file with does not exist so you must add 'w' parameter to open function.

Comment: Note that if you want to ADD data to an already existing file (or create one if it doesn't already exist), you have to use 'a' instead of 'w', because with 'w' it will overwrite the content of the file.

Comment: @ Madbeap and Swifty. Thanks for your prompt response. I tried that and this is what i got - AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'w'

Comment: In your code you are using a non existing method `f.w()` and you have to use `f.write()`. Check the code I shared.